# How to avoid entering the same value that had been input by the user?

Tags: node.js, express

Problem: When I am using `Postman`, I was trying to `POST` a data but it is still returning `200` even if the value was already been in a server.

This is my code

```
// Create and Save a new Note
exports.create = (req, res) => {
   // Validate request
   if(!req.body.content) {
     return res.status(400).send({
       message: "Note content can not be empty"
   });
 }

  if (req.body.content.length < 5) {
    return res.status(422).send({
      message: "Note cannot be less than 5 characters"
  });
 }

  if (req.body.title.length < 5) {
    return res.status(422).send({
      message: "Title cannot be less than 5 characters"
  })
 }

 // Create a Note
  const note = new Note({
    title: req.body.title || "Untitled Note",
    content: req.body.content
  });

// Save Note in the database
note.save()
  .then(data => {
    res.send(data);
}).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Note."
   });
});
};
```

Expected output: I should be getting a error message on postman that the value was already been posted. Hence you cannot create another record if that value is already been added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [insertOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/) of mongodb

```
  Note.insertOne({
      title: req.body.title || "Untitled Note",
      content: req.body.content
  });
```